# Payment gateway for iPhone application for purchase physical item

Tags: iphone, ios, payment-gateway, payment

I want to use payment gateway in my iPhone application. We want to purchase/order few physical items like pizza or any other food items. So please let me know which payment gateway should i use. And apple will approve that too.

thanks

Comment: `PayPal` would be the best one. But as u r referring Pizza-like item, local popular bank payment would be great idea.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)? There are plenty of question regarding this. You could have searched before asking question. -1 for that.

Comment: @rohan-patel I did not tried but I did some research and find that many people says that should use in-app-purchase or paypal but not sure it will approved or not.

Answer (score 1):

Buying a physical item or similar external item is perfectly OK in an app. You can use any gateway you want such as PayPal. I work in travel and we handle things like hotel reservations with our own payment system.

In-app purchase is *only* for things you buy in the app that change the app's features (like virtual hats in a game or unlocking app features) and is the only way Apple allows you to do this. It's also allowable (see Amazon's Kindle Book app) to support purchase in a website and have the app update the data, however you cannot mention this in the app or even provide a link to the online store. Still only for stuff inside the app.

Personally I am not in favor of PayPal as they tend to screw people for all sorts of strange reasons. There are many options out there you should research, often it depends on what countries you want to support as few work everywhere whether your company can meet whatever requirements the gateway company needs.